# invalid geometry after sf_transform to Winkel-Tripel from WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global

Tags: r, r-sf, map-projections

I have written code for a global equal-area hexagonal grid. I can create and plot the grid using the WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global projection. I would like to re-project this grid onto the Winkel-Tripel projection. The plotting works for some combinations of base map and bounding box but not for others. When it doesn't work it returns the following error.

```
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 2 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

I have tried lots of combinations of maps, bounding boxes derived from maps, and manual bounding boxes but can't seem to get it to work for the whole world or large countries with northern latitudes like the United States, Canada, and Russia. When it doesn't work, I've found that some geometries became invalid after transformation to Winkel-Tripel but st_make_valid() doesn't work on them. See below for code that works and two examples of code that returns the error above when trying to plot the ggplot objects.

Thanks for whatever assistance you can provide!

Glenn

#####################

**Example 1**

Code that works

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

################
#map
world = ne_countries(scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  st_transform(crs=4236)

map = world[world$admin == 'Norway', ]

#bounding box from map
bbox = st_bbox(map) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_sf()

# WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global
map_6933 = st_transform(map, 6933)
bbox_6933 = st_transform(bbox,6933)
bbox_grid_6933 <- st_make_grid(bbox_6933,
                               n = c(25,25),
                               what = 'polygons',
                               square = FALSE,
                               flat_topped = TRUE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(area = st_area(.)/c(1000*1000))

#Winkel-Tripel
wintri <- "+proj=wintri +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +over"
map_wintri = st_transform(map_6933, wintri)
bbox_wintri = st_transform(bbox_6933, wintri)
bbox_grid_wintri = st_transform(bbox_grid_6933,wintri)


p_6933 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = bbox_grid_6933,
          aes(fill = units::drop_units(area)),alpha=0.75) +
  geom_sf(data = bbox_6933,
          fill = NA, color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = map_6933,
          fill = NA, color = 'white')

p_wintri <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = bbox_grid_wintri,
          aes(fill = units::drop_units(area)),alpha=0.75) +
  geom_sf(data = bbox_wintri,
          fill = NA, color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = map_wintri,
          fill = NA, color = 'white')

cowplot::plot_grid(p_6933, p_wintri, nrow = 2,labels = c('6933','wintri'))
```

Expected result...

[image: Expected result]

#####################

**Example 2**

Code does not work if `map = world[world$admin == 'Norway', ]` is changed to

```
map = world[world$admin == 'Canada', ]
```

error:

```
> cowplot::plot_grid(p_6933, p_wintri, nrow = 2,labels = c('6933','wintri'))
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 2 - must be 0 or >= 4.
```

#####################

**Example 3**

Code does not work if `map = world[world$admin == 'Norway', ]` is changed to

```
map = world
```

error:

```
> cowplot::plot_grid(p_6933, p_wintri, nrow = 2,labels = c('6933','wintri'))
Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, x, y) : 
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements.
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how you pulled the country data, however sf has issues when loading the geometries for natural earth. You can turn off s2 `st_use_s2(FALSE)` for loading geometries but this has drawbacks https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1732. Your script works sometimes because not every country has invalid geometries. You could also try manually fixing the geometries that are invalid https://github.com/r-spatial/s2/issues/99.

Comment: apologies, I have added in the function I used to get my base map, ne_countries().

Comment: I'm confused by why invalid geometries for a country would cause the hex-grid to have invalid geometries after st_transform to Winkel-Tripel. The Winkel-Tripel projection of the world shapefile plots just fine but when I try to plot just the Winkel-Tripel hex-grid, I get the error. Thanks!